# What does "that's me" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've searched the online dictionaries but I didn't find the meaning of

> "that’s me".

So could you please explain it to me?

The full text:

> “I’m an attorney.” So, it is him. “Who do you think committed the
>   murders in this hotel?” He hesitates, and then says, “I don’t know.”
>   She remains silent, waiting for him to continue. “The others—Beverly
>   and Henry and Matthew, especially Henry—seemed convinced last night
>   that it was Ian. They were looking at him as if they thought he was
>   going to murder us all.” He rubs his eyes tiredly before going on.
>   “Perhaps it was relief at finally having someone to blame. They
>   desperately needed to know who it was and they thought they did.” He
>   looks up at her. “In my experience, the human mind doesn’t like to
>   deal with uncertainty.” He tells her, then, what he hadn’t told her
>   before, the way they turned on Ian. “Jesus,” she says, imagining it.
>   “They calmed down. I’ll never forget how relieved Ian looked.” “You
>   may have saved his life.” “I don’t think it would have actually come
>   to that.” He shrugs and looks up at her cynically. “But **that’s me**,
>   protector and defender of the accused, no matter how heinous the
>   crime.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'But that's me', or sometimes, 'but that's just me' is a common expression. It can mean variously, either:

> That's my opinion.

This meaning is usually used when someone expresses an opinion at variance to that of a group of others, indicating that they won't change their opinion, but at the same time, they are happy to allow other people to hold to their alternate opinion(s).

> That's just the way I am.

This meaning is usually used when one's actions or behaviours are out of sync with the people around them. So, in this case he does not think that Beverley, Henry and Matthew would have hurt Ian, although the girl thinks they may have killed him.

Answer (score 3):

When someone says

> **that's me**
>   **that's just me**
>   **well that's me**

They mean that's how they are in life, how they live their life, **that's me** ***being me***.
It can be interpreted as being unapologetic for the way one is.

> Most people like chocolate, but I like strawberry, but **that's me**.

Answer (score 3):

It can also be paraphrased "That's who I am", that is, it is an acknowledgment of one's *predictable* character or nature.

> But that’s me, protector and defender of the accused, no matter how heinous the crime.

Compare:

> But that's me, always the last one to get the joke.
>
> But that's me, out of bed, showered, and ready to go two hours ahead of time.
>
> But that's me, always taken in by a good sales pitch.

It doesn't have to be said of oneself:

> But that's Joe, always the clown.
>
> But that's Joe, ever the good samaritan.
>
> But that's Joe, always the first to volunteer.

Comment: +1 for adding that the expression can be used in the third person as well.